# npm shrinkwrap produces different output on two installs

Tags: node.js

I have two machines with the same repository and node/npm versions

Running Shrinkwrap on one gives me

```
   "globals": {
          "version": "6.4.1",
          "from": "globals@>=6.4.0 <7.0.0",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/globals/-/globals-6.4.1.tgz"
        },
```

On the other i get

```
    "globals": {
      "version": "6.4.1",
      "from": "https://registry.npmjs.org/globals/-/globals-6.4.1.tgz",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/globals/-/globals-6.4.1.tgz"
    },
```

I don't know whats happening